# If $X$ and $Y$ are Lindelöf's (respectively countably compact) spaces so that $X\times Y$ is a Lindelöf's (respectively countably compact) space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I was trying to prove it using basic open sets of the product space $X\times Y$ but I don't get anything. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

The product of two Lindelöf spaces need not be Lindelöf. One of the simpler examples is the Sorgenfrey line: it is hereditarily Lindelöf, but its square is not even Lindelöf. This is covered in [this post](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/a-note-on-the-sorgenfrey-line/) from Dan Ma’s Topology Blog.

It’s harder to find an example of two countably compact spaces whose product is not countably compact, but they do exist; the first was published by J. Novák in ‘On the Cartesian product of two compact spaces’, *Fundamenta Mathematicae* $40$ $(1953)$, $106$-$112$, which is freely available [here](https://eudml.org/doc/213312). The notation is rather old-fashioned, so it may be helpful to give a rough description: he showed that there are countably compact subsets $Y$ and $Z$ of $\beta\Bbb N$ such that $Y\cup Z=\beta\Bbb N$ and $Y\cap Z=\Bbb N$, whose product $Y\times Z$ contains the infinite closed discrete set $\{\langle n,n\rangle:n\in\Bbb N\}$ and is therefore not countably compact.