# The product of limit point compact Hausdorff spaces is not limit point compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples

Let $X, Y$ be limit point compact Hausdorff spaces (to be clear, a space is said to be limit point compact if every infinite subset of it has a limit point). Is it true that $X \times Y$ is limit point compact? The answer should be negative but I can't find a counterexample. Can you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Limit point compactness is equivalent to countable compactness in $T_1$ spaces, so it suffices to find a pair of countably compact $T_1$ spaces whose product is not countably compact. In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/477145/12042) you’ll find a reference to the first published example of such a pair, together with a brief description; the spaces in question are not just $T_1$, but Tikhonov, being subspaces of the compact Hausdorff space $\beta\Bbb N$.

Comment: thank you for your answer, please just give me the time to put all the pieces together before accepting it :)

Comment: @user01123581321345589144...: You’re welcome; take whatver time you need.