# The product of limit point compact spaces is limit point compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, product-space

Assuming the Tychonoff theorem that arbitrary product of compact spaces is compact, is it true that the product of limit point compact spaces is limit point compact? If not, are there any counterexamples?

I've read [The product of limit point compact Hausdorff spaces is not limit point compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538674/the-product-of-limit-point-compact-hausdorff-spaces-is-not-limit-point-compact), [If $X$ and $Y$ are Lindelöf's (respectively countably compact) spaces so that $X\times Y$ is a Lindelöf's (respectively countably compact) space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477142/if-x-and-y-are-lindel%c3%b6fs-respectively-countably-compact-spaces-so-that-x/477145#477145), and the second link in the second one. But the link says something different with what I know(for example, 'The Cartesian product of two compact regular spaces need not be compact', Theorem 4 in the link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper by J. Novák in my second link at your second link uses an older terminology: what he calls *compact* is our *countably compact*, and for our *compact* he uses the term *bicompact*. The example in his Theorem $4$ is an example of two countably compact Tikhonov spaces whose product is not countably compact. It is also an example of two Tikhonov limit point compact spaces whose product is not limit point compact.

Comment: @Sphere the last holds as for $T_1$ spaces (which these examples are, as they are  Tikhonov even) "limit point compact" = "countably compact".